# multiple processes of video processing to GPU cores

Tags: cuda, ffmpeg, gpu, video-processing

Can we assign a number of processes (i.e. 100-500 processes) to GPU, each process running on a GPU core?
In my application of video processing, I have to use ffmpeg library to proceed video and audio. If there are like more than 100 or even 500 such independent processes, I guess it's faster to assign each process to a GPU. However, I don't know if we can do it, and to do it, what libraries, tools are necessary? CUDA?

Comment: GPGPU processing doesn't work that way.

Comment: right, I know about the other way. I just need to know if this way was possible :)

Comment: I wish this were possible...that would be awesome :) There is some GPU offload options like NVCENC or what not FWIW, but those just do it all in GPU.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we assign a number of processes (i.e. 100-500 processes) to GPU, each process running on a GPU core?

No, you can't.  In general it's not possible to schedule *anything* on a GPU core per se.  This level of "scheduling" is handled mainly by the mechanics of the CUDA architecture and runtime system.

The basic idea is to expose parallelism at a fairly low level in your code (e.g. at the loop level) and with proper use of a GPU acceleration syntax (such as CUDA, OpenACC, OpenCL, etc.) the GPU can often make such elements of your program run faster.

But the GPU is not designed to be a drop-in replacement for CPU cores.  There is the scheduling factor that I mentioned already, as well as the fact that codes generally need to be compiled for the GPU specifically.

Comment: Thank you for your information! Your answer saves a lot of my time.